# How to detect when the browser is too small and then tell visitors to enlarge browser to continue?

Tags: jquery, browser, popup, detect

Is it possible to create a jquery script, there can detect when the browser is to small and then tell your visitors to enlarge browser to continue?

Does anyone know a jquery script for that?

Comment: You don't really need jQuery for this. Just use `window.screen.width`, `.height` to get the screen size

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? A good start would be to search for ways to find the screen width and height.

Comment: If an user can't figure out when the browser window is too small for them to use your page properly, said user shouldn't even be on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

What about when their browser is maximized and then it is still too small?

Will they have to constantly deal with the message?

Here is a sample script:

```
if( window.clientWidth < 1000 ){ 
 alert("Send your business elsewhere"); 
}
```

This idea of forcing the user to resize seems too invasive to be of any use though, because users should determine their window size. Responsive design is to mold the view to the user, not to mold the user to your view.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone makes good points about the validity of doing this. But -

```
var tooSmall = 500;
var wHeight = $(window).height();
var wWidth = $(window).width();
if ( wWidth < tooSmall ){
    //Tell them so!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible with jQuery, something like this.

```
if($(window).width() < 960) {
    // Do something when less than 960
}
```

Or plain JavaScript

```
if(document.width < 960) {
    // Do something when less than 960
}
```

**Alternative CSS solution**

Since you don't give any context, it is hard to tell what the best solution would be, but another option would be to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries) and show a message when then window is below a certain width.

The nice thing about this is that you don't have to worry about listening for window-resize events etc. too keep track of the current screen-size. The browser will take care of it for you. It will likely be far more efficient than a JS-solution as well, if you go down the road of listening for window-resize events. Further will also handle the case where the user has JavaScript disabled.

*Markup:*

```
<div id="error-message">Please enlarge your window for the site to work</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#error-message {
   display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
   #error-message {
        display: block;
   }
}
```